# how to send array of objects in spring boot post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My request looks like in postman

```
[


    {
            "skill_name":"cms",
            "skill_desc":"php",
            "is_cerificate_completed":true,
            "emp_skill_id":-1,
            "emp_id":3,
            "status":"SMP",
            "reason_for_reject":"",
            "active":true,
            "submitted":true,
            "user_id":3

        },


{
        "skill_name":"wordpress",
        "skill_desc":"php",
        "is_cerificate_completed":true,
        "emp_skill_id":-1,
        "emp_id":3,
        "status":"SMP",
        "reason_for_reject":"",
        "active":true,
        "submitted":true,
        "user_id":3

    }
```

]

I am trying to send this as my post request, the issue i am facing is that only the second object is passed to the stored procedure in MySQL, Please Help me to send array of objects to spring boot server using POST Request.

```
public void saveEmployeeSkillMatrix(List<EmployeeSkillMatrix> emp_skill_matrix) {
        StoredProcedureQuery save = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_iu_skill_matrix");

        save.registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_emp_skill_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_emp_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_skill_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_skill_desc", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_is_certificate_completed", Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_status", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_reason_for_reject", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_active", Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_submitted", Boolean.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("p_usr_id", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("error_msg", String.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);

        for(EmployeeSkillMatrix esm : emp_skill_matrix)
        {
            save.setParameter("p_emp_skill_id", esm.getEmp_skill_id());
            save.setParameter("p_emp_id", esm.getEmp_id());
            save.setParameter("p_skill_name", esm.getSkill_name());
            save.setParameter("p_skill_desc", esm.getSkill_desc());
            save.setParameter("p_is_certificate_completed", esm.isCertificate_completed());
            save.setParameter("p_status", esm.getStatus());
            save.setParameter("p_reason_for_reject", esm.getReason_for_reject());
            save.setParameter("p_active", esm.isActive());
            save.setParameter("p_submitted", esm.isSubmitted());
            save.setParameter("p_usr_id", esm.getUser_id());
            save.setParameter("error_msg", new String("error_msg"));
        }

        String errString = (String) save.getOutputParameterValue("error_msg");

    }
```

Comment: Try to change `List<EmployeeSkillMatrix> emp_skill_matrix` to `EmployeeSkillMatrix[] emp_skill_matrix`. I guess spring needs to know what type of Object he needs to map

Comment: I don't know for sure but I suspect you need to save inside the loop at the end.

Comment: Indeed. You need to add `save.execute();` at end of you `for` loop

Comment: Maybe you should think about reading the `StoredProcedureQuery` interface. 
Maybe you should think about using `StoredProcedureQuery::execute`or `StoredProcedureQuery::executeUpdate`.
Maybe you should use `errString`.

When I read you code, I think the main problem is, it look like you don't understand how stored procedure and Java work together.

Comment: i got Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults @Valijon if i add save.execute()

Comment: @Zorglube you are right, since i am a beginner please explain how the interface works,

Comment: @KathiravanRamaswamy : StackOverflow is intended to share information and ideas about software development problem, it's not about giving lessons.

Comment: Struggling here for two days to solve the problem please suggest me a idea to solve it.@Zorglube

Comment: @KathiravanRamaswamy : As I told you, seeing your code, you do not have an technical problem, you have an knowledge problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198146/discussion-between-kathiravan-ramaswamy-and-zorglube).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a DTO object encapsulating the JSON input array:

```
public class EmployeeSkillMatrixInDto {
    private List<EmployeeSkillMatrix> employees;
    public List<EmployeeSkillMatrix> getEmployees() { return employees; }
    public void setEmployees(List<EmployeeSkillMatrix> {
        this.employees = employees; 
    }
}
```

Change the JSON input to:

```
 { "employees": [ ... your employees array here ... ] }
```

And finally the controller such as:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public YourCustomResponse upload(@RequestBody EmployeeSkillMatrixInDto inDto) {
    yourService.saveEmployeeSkillMatrix(inDto.getEmployees());
    //... rest of your response handling ...
}
```